# AngularJS - Delete request not working correctly

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to sort out this issue with my delete URL. Basically, I want it to repeat and delete the URL. I assumed it was a for loop issue and still do, but it doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
if (toDeleteValue.length > 0) {
  var deleteRequest = {};
  deleteRequest.values = toDeleteValue;

  for (var i = 0; i < toDeleteValue.length; i++) {
    var deleteUrl = "api/users/" + $scope.targetEntity.id + "/values?value=" + values;

    $http.delete(deleteUrl)
    .then(function(response) {
    });
  }
}
```

My url currently is this:
`http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/values?value=dwqdwq,wegergem`

I would like to change it from one, to two instead depending how many entities I would like to delete.
`http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/values?value=dwqdwq`
`http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/values?value=wegergem`

Comment: What is `toDeleteValue` (what is its type, what does it contain?). Same question for `values`. Then, based on the answers to these questions, what do you expect your code to do, and what does it do instead? Side note, why do you define a variable `deleteRequest` that you never use anywhere? And why do you loop over all the elements of `toDeleteValue` if you never use the current  element inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you're trying to delete each value 1 at a time...which is problematic in itself...

but instead of this

```
var deleteUrl = "api/users/" + $scope.targetEntity.id + "/values?value=" + values;
```

you need this

```
var deleteUrl = "api/users/" + $scope.targetEntity.id + "/values?value=" + toDeleteValue[i];
```

In my opinion, a better solution would be to add a new call that would accept an array of values and only make 1 call to delete instead of looping.